# Is naked addition and subtraction safe in transfer and transferFrom?

Tags: solidity, erc-20

I'm implementing my own ERC20 token and trying to figure out best practices by looking at existing implementations. I found that DAI has [addition and subtraction functions](https://github.com/makerdao/dss/blob/c8d4c806691dacb903ff281b81f316bea974e4c7/src/dai.sol#L49-L54) that appear to prevent integer overflow in the transfer and transferFrom methods.

```
function add(uint x, uint y) internal pure returns (uint z) {
    require((z = x + y) >= x);
}
function sub(uint x, uint y) internal pure returns (uint z) {
    require((z = x - y) <= x);
}
```

Whereas the Consensys reference implementation [just subtracts and adds balances](https://github.com/ConsenSys/Tokens/blob/fdf687c69d998266a95f15216b1955a4965a0a6d/contracts/eip20/EIP20.sol#L50-L51) without performing any such check.

```
    balances[_to] += _value;
    balances[_from] -= _value;
```

My intuition is that my token doesn't need these methods, as it has a fixed supply far less than MAX_UINT256. Am I missing an attack vector? Is there a more authoritative source to copy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That contract you mentioned is 3+ years old and an Integer overflow & underflow attack was discovered after it (https://github.com/SmartContractSecurity/SWC-registry/blob/master/entries/SWC-101.md), you shouldn't trust that repo, it is unmaintained. Use openzeppelin's SafeMath for arithmetic operations if you need it